# Proving this $\gcd(2^n-1,3^n+2)=1$ for all postive integers $n$

Tags: number-theory

I have found 
$$\gcd(2-1,3+2)=\gcd(1,5)=1$$
$$\gcd(2^2-1,3^2+2)=\gcd(3,11)=1$$
$$\gcd(2^3-1,3^3+2)=\gcd(7,29)=1$$
$$\gcd(2^4-1,3^4+2)=\gcd(15,83)=1$$
$$\gcd(2^5-1,3^5+2)=\gcd(31,245)=1$$
$$\cdots\cdots$$
I  conjecture $\gcd(2^n-1,3^n+2)=1$,I can't prove this?

Comment: Your conjecture is false for $n=176$ (with the GCD being $257$). See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\gcd%282^{176}-1,3^{176}%2B2%29).

Comment: How found this $n=176?$

Comment: Python script...

Comment: this is why a mathematician without computer is a diver without suit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have checked with Sage that, for $n=176$, we have

\begin{align*}
2^n-1 &= 95780971304118053647396689196894323976171195136475135 \\
3^n+2 &= 940461086986004843694934910131056317906479029659199959555574885740211572136210345923,
\end{align*}
and $gcd(2^n-1,3^n+2) = 257$.

$n=176$ is the smallest. The next ones are: 432, 688, 944.

Comment: Funny enough, their GCDs are all $257$ as well... Perhaps it's a good time to extend the conjecture...

Comment: And $176, 432, 688, 944, 1200, \dots$ are all forms of $n=256m-80.$ Are there any integers not following rule?

Comment: Looks like $n=176+256k$, $k=0,1,2,\dots$.

Comment: You are right for 'small' values of $n$, but for $n =22528$ we have 65537, which is also a prime number.

Comment: Well perhaps to powers of $2$ plus $1$ then...

Comment: @choco_addicted, For all such values $n=256m-80$, we have $257|\mathrm{gcd}(2^n-1,3^n+2)$.

Comment: @emiliocba Also, if $n=22528+65536m$, $m\geq 0$, then $65537|\mathrm{gcd}(2^n-1, 3^n+2)$.